# Android Facebook sdk v4 likeview language

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I use android facebook sdk V4 to display LikeView button.

All is ok with the implementation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

My problem is on likeview page that is always in English. I want it on French language when my device is on French language. Is it possible ?

[LikeView screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGPTR.png)

Comment: i have the problem